The definition of mass density from a mathematician's perspective
In calculus, $dy/dx$ implies that $y$ is a function of $x$. Now let's see two examples from physics:
Temperature ($T$) is an intensive quantity, and the derivative $dT/dx$ has the same implication as above, because temperature is a function of position ($x$) indeed.
Mass ($m$) is an extensive quantity, and the definition of mass density, i.e. $dm/dV$, where $V$ denotes volume, doesn't imply that mass is a function of volume.
Physicists sometimes use mathematical notation and tools in less rigorous ways compared to professional mathematicians. Can the definition of mass density be regarded as an example? If so, what is the rigorous way of defining mass density?

Of course mass is (or, at least, can be) a function of volume. For example when you pour incompressible liquid into a vessel, the mass of liquid accumulated is obviously a function of its volume. :)

@CiaPan, " incompressible liquid" means a liquid with homogeneous mass density. That's is a very simplified case.

@CiaPan, So, in your example, we have a simple linear function $m(V)=\rho V$.

You would argue that density $\rho$ is an intensive quantity and is a function of location, so the integral of $\rho$ over the locations in a 3D object would give the mass of the object.  Reversing the process (the limit of $\frac{m}{V}$ as the part of the object considered shrinks towards a point, if this exists) gives you the density.

@Henry, Let's consider the one-dimensional case. Temperature is a function of position, but mass is not (in continuum mechanics). We can talk of the mass in a given interval or volume, not the mass at a given position.

@apadana I think that is what I said.

@Henry, Sorry. I think I shouldn't have posted this question. When your brain is exhausted, even the most basic things can be confusing.

If you're looking for some trippy ideas, the user @Anixx's example of lattices having negative dimensions here is directly motivated by the intuition of how a "density function works". In the case of his lattices its "# of points/length of line" that is being measured to make the lattice negative dimensional. I felt that pondering on that gave me a clearer idea on "what a density function" vs a "measure" is and how they are kind of two sides of the same abstract phenomenon.

Density is mass per unit volume. The derivative of mass with respect to volume only makes sense if mass if a function of volume. If there is a density then mass is a function of volume because the mass increases/decreases as the volume increases/decreases.

To a mathematician, this is all done using measure theory. Within that theory, mass $m$ is a mathematical object called a measure.
To say what this means, let's imagine some amount of mass being distributed over some portion of 3-dimensional space represented as a subset $D \subset \mathbb R^3$. The distribution is perhaps not uniform, but (with certain formal restrictions) each subset $A \subset D$ is assigned a real number $m(A) \ge 0$ called the mass of that subset. This assignment must satisfy some constraints: if $A_1,A_2$ are two disjoint subsets whose union is $A$ then $m(A_1 \cup A_2) = m(A_1)+m(A_2)$; for formal reasons one must also assume that if $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ are countably many, pairwise disjoint subsets then $m(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots) = m(A_1)+m(A_2)+m(A_3)+\cdots$.
To say just a few words about the constraints on $A$, for set theoretical reasons this does not work if one allows $A$ to be an arbitrary subset of $D$, so what one does is to restrict $A$ in some manner; one of the usual restrictions is that $A$ should be a  Lebesgue subset.
Volume $V$ is also a measure defined on Lebesgue subsets, in the exact same sense as stated above. One uses basic multivariable calculus to compute $V(A)$ for sufficiently nice subset $A$, or the more advanced Lebesgue integration for arbitrary Lebesgue subsets.
Finally, the mass density $\frac{dm}{dV}$ is the Radon-Nykodym derivative of the measure $m$ with respect to the measure $V$. This derivative is simply a function $\frac{dm}{dV} : D \to [0,\infty)$, and it has its own weird mathematical formula expressing it as some kind of limit, but its chief property is that it is characterized by the expected equation
$$m(A) = \iiint_A \frac{dm}{dV} \, dV
$$
This integral, again, is either an ordinary multivariable calculus triple integral using $dV  = dx \, dy \, dz$, or it is the more advanced Lebesgue integral, depending on the nature of the function $\frac{dm}{dV}$ and the set $A$.
There is still one more formal requirement in order for this all to work: if a subset $A$ has zero volume, i.e. if $V(A)=0$, then also $m(A)=0$. A mathematician would word this requirement by saying that the measure $m$ must be absolutely continuous with respect to the measure $V$. This rules out things that physicists love to speculate about, such as point masses and masses distributed along a line. If that's where you want to go, then you'll need more advanced functional analysis with distributions and so on, like the Dirac delta function.

"$m(A_1\cup A_2)=A$" - The left side is a number, but the right side is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

Oops, fixed, thanks.

”or it is the more advanced Lebesgue integral, depending on the nature of $A$.” Well, it also depends on the function $\frac{dm}{dV}$; for instance you could have $\frac{dm}{dV}$ being the indicator of a fat Cantor set and $A$ as nice as you wish  (a compact interval say); then we still need to resort to the Lebesgue integral.

Well, I didn't really want to delve too deeply into details for purposes of this post. Of course $\frac{dm}{dV}$ is a Lebesgue measurable function in general, and if it is not continuous then yes, we might well have to use the Lebesgue integral.

But I added a few words to address your point.

Normally measures are non-negative, e.g. length, area, volume, mass. But also signed and even complex measures can be considered. An example of signed measure is the amount of electric charge within a region, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative $dQ/dV$ is of course the electric charge density.

"$m(A_1\cup A_2)=m(A)$" - This is a trivial consequence of $A_1\cup A_2=A$, and is no constraint on $m$.

Oops again, fixed, thanks.
